# What is this JavaScript construct called

Tags: javascript

I've found a JavaScript arrow function that looks something like this:

```
([a,b,c]) => {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c = 'x';
}
```

How is this function invoked? Also, what is this construct called?

Comment: [Destructuring parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an arrow function, which gets an array as a parameter and destruct the first 3 values into the corresponding parameters - `a,b,c`. But it must be assigned to a variable or be self invoked.

`() => {}` - [**Arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

`[a,b,c]` - [**Array destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Example

```js
const func = ([a,b,c]) => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
};

func([1,2,3,4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([a, b, c]) => {}
```

The first part is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parameters, which takes an array as parameter and returns the variables with the values of the position.

The later assignment makes no sense with the given code.